# React Native: Android: Different border colors with borderRadius

Tags: react-native

I can't seem to find any documentation describing a difference in behavior with border colors on Android vs iOS. The code below works great on iOS but not on Android. Android decides to ignore the blue border all together.

The problem goes away if the `borderRadius` is removed.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Modal,
    Text,
    View
  } from 'react-native';

  export default class test extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={[styles.innerContainer, {borderTopColor: 'blue'}]}></View>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      padding: 20
    },
    innerContainer: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#111',
      height: 200
    },
  });

  AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```

Comment: Where are you will apply that class? Please show us the code.

Comment: I've updated the post appropriately. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem goes away if the borderRadius is removed.

Yes, [there's a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9262) on Android that once you do this, your whole border is set or gone.

Best bet is to use a wrapper view or don't use radius.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<View style={{ borderTopLeftRadius:10, borderTopRightRadius:10 }} />
<View/> //don't use border radius here 
<View style={{ borderBottomLeftRadius:10, borderBottomRightRadius:10 }} />
```